# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' using googletrans and pyjokes

Tags: python

```
joke = pyjokes.get_joke() ## Get a joke.
        translator = Translator() ## Initalize a Translator object.
        print( translator.translate(joke, dest='hi').text)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "A.I.py", line 206, in <module>
print( translator.translate(joke, dest='hi').text)   File "C:\Users\NEERAJ KUSHWAH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 182, in translate
data = self._translate(text, dest, src, kwargs)   File "C:\Users\NEERAJ KUSHWAH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 78, in _translate
token = self.token_acquirer.do(text)   File "C:\Users\NEERAJ KUSHWAH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py", line 194, in do
self._update()   File "C:\Users\NEERAJ KUSHWAH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py", line 62, in _update
code = self.RE_TKK.search(r.text).group(1).replace('var ', '') AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: That's a known bug: https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans/issues/234

Comment: how to fix this

Comment: Have you looked at the issue @ThierryLathuille has mentioned?

If so, have you tried the possible fix, that was mentioned?
`pip install googletrans==4.0.0-rc1`